# Merging two files by a single column in unix

Tags: linux, unix, merge

I would like to merge two files by one column in unix.

I have file_a:

```
subjectid name age  
12 Jane 16  
24 Kristen 90  
15 Clarke 78  
23 Joann 31
```

I have another file_b:

```
subjectid prob_disease  
12 0.009  
24 0.738  
15 0.392  
23 1.2E-5
```

I would like to merge these files in the command line. I'd like to merge files a and b by subjectid. Since each file is about 2 million lines long, I tried in R but it froze due to the amount of data, could someone please help me do this in linux? 
Desired output:

```
subjectid prob_disease name age  
12 0.009 Jane 16  
24 0.738 Kristen 90   
15 0.392 Clarke 78  
23 1.2E-5 Joanna 31
```

Please help and thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out [`join(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join).  In your case, you don't even need any flags:

```
$ join file_b file_a
subjectid prob_disease name age
12 0.009 Jane 16
24 0.738 Kristen 90
15 0.392 Clarke 78
23 1.2E-5 Joann 31
```

Comment: This works great as long as the lines are already lined up by ID, if not they'll need to be sorted.

Comment: ... in which case you should also check out [`sort(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort).

Comment: I was going to suggest an awk hack with the two files, but join(1) is clearly the right answer here.  No pre-sorting necessary with awk, though.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `join` command:

```
$ cat test.1
12 Jane 16
24 Kristen 90
15 Clarke 78
23 Joann 31 
$ cat test.2
12 0.009
24 0.738
15 0.392
23 1.2E-5 
$ join -j1 -o 2.1,2.2,1.2,1.3  <(sort test.1) <(sort test.2)
12 0.009 Jane 16
15 0.392 Clarke 78
23 1.2E-5 Joann 31
24 0.738 Kristen 90
$
```