# merging two files based on two columns

Tags: linux, unix, join, merge

I have a question very similar to a previous post:
[Merging two files by a single column in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575972/merging-two-files-by-a-single-column-in-unix)
but i want to merge my data based on two columns (The orders are the same, so no need to sort).
Example,

subjectid subID2 name age
12 121 Jane 16
24 241 Kristen 90
15 151 Clarke 78
23 231 Joann 31

subjectid subID2 prob_disease
12 121 0.009
24 241 0.738
15 151 0.392
23 231 1.2E-5

And the output to look like

subjectid SubID2 prob_disease name age
12 121 0.009 Jane 16
24 241 0.738 Kristen 90
15 151 0.392 Clarke 78
23 231 1.2E-5 Joanna 31

when i use join it only considers the first column(subjectid) and repeats the SubID2 column.
Is there a way of doing this with join or some other way please? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

join command doesn't have an option to scan more than one field as a joining criteria. Hence, you will have to add some intelligence into the mix. Assuming your files has a FIXED number of fields on each line, you can use something like this:

```
join f1 f2 | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$6}'
```

provided the the field counts are as given in your examples. Otherwise, you need to adjust the scope of print in the awk command, by adding or taking away some fields.

Answer (score 2):

If the orders are identical, you could still merge by a single column and specify the format of which columns to output, like:

```
join -o '1.1 1.2 2.3 1.3 1.4' file_a file_b
```

as described in [join(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join).