# awk join multiple files column-wise using 1st Column for mapping

Tags: bash, join, awk

**This is different from the [Join Multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10726471/5202279) as the first column is used to make the values in 2nd column while joining.**

want to combine/append/join multiple files having 2 columns each using first column as key. awk is preferred but other suggestion are welcome. whatever code kindly do explain it so I can also learn.

file1

```
frames rmsd
     1 1.2
     2 0.2
     3 1.2
     4 0.2
```

file 2

```
frames rmsd
     1 2.2
     2 3.2
     3 5.2
```

I have more than 30 files.

desired output

all_file

```
frames rmsd1 rmsd2 ... rmsd32
     1 1.2 2.2
     2 0.2 3.3
     3 1.2 5.2
     4 0.2
```

want to do it in awk.
single line with explanation would be appreciated.

Edit 1

I know it can be done with join for 2 files but can join be used with bash expansion file{0..5}.dat

I wanted to use awk because i have other files too which need to be converted to single files.

Edit 2

Solution

[join multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726471/join-multiple-files/52072117#52072117)

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575972/merging-two-files-by-a-single-column-in-unix

Comment: Using the `join` command as suggested in the 'duplicate'. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726471/join-multiple-files shows how to do it with multiple files. Furthermore, you will end up with the wrong header. The header can be changed afterwards with `awk '(NR==1){for(i=2l;i<=NF;++i) $i=$i (i-1)}1'`

Comment: i know i can use join but i have more than 30 files,  can use join for 30 files at once ?

Comment: You can use it like `join file1 file2 | join - file3 | join - file4 |  ...`

Comment: this is not practical for suppose 200 files.

Comment: Just write bash script to do this. That's what loop is for.

Comment: @RohitModee Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52072117/8344060

Comment: i dont want to use a loop in bash. i need an awk one-liner for this.

Comment: @RohitModee there is an awk one-liner there

Comment: @kvantour thank-you very much for that answer it did it.  stackoverflow.com/a/52072117/8344060